# how to optimize convert IDataRecord to myobject, performance

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, casting, compiler-optimization

i am working with a pocket pc

i have this

> c#

code

[image]

and this is de C# code for new ClietnesTxt(row)

[image]

i need optimize it, but i dont have idea i would convert 1 by 1 because i believe that do it slow.

you could see this took about 3.5 seconds for 70 records.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text - just copy and paste the text into the question (and make sure it's indented suitably). That's *much* easier for everyone to read.

Comment: You should run it on your pocket pc to see if really takes that long.  You cannot always trust the time used in a debugger.  If it takes that long you might need to look at the query that you run or the amount of data that you read.

Comment: this this take that time, por that i want to optimize it.